# Error when using GGally::ggpairs: "object 'ContinuousRange' not found"

Tags: r

I run `ggpairs` on my data and get this error:

```
 library(GGally)
 ggpairs(mix[, c("soc", "neg", "b")])
 # Error in structure(list(call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  : 
 # object 'ContinuousRange' not found
```

Here's my data

```
 structure(list(soc = c(-10.31, 14, 4, 1.5, 1.56), neg = c(-1.66, 
-10.75, -0.63, -1.24, -0.9), b = c("2", "2", "3", "3", "2")), .Names =  c("soc", 
"neg", "b"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The same issue happened when I applied it on a different set of data.

Comment: I don't get any error. I'm using GGally 0.5.0 and ggplot2 1.0.1.

Comment: Also works for me, same versions

Comment: should get  my package updated then, thanks

Comment: My versions are the same, but I still see this error

Comment: @Lucia I _think_ the error may be related to the `scales` package. Check that you have the latest version (0.2.5). Update all relevant packages and install the latest R version (3.2.2), restart and try in a fresh session.

Comment: Have justed tried, the problem is still there